# SwiftUI: How to use circular img cropper with UIImagepicker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage, imagepicker

I have this code that allows the user to pick an image and then crop it.

But is it possible to make the image cropper circular instead of being a square??

This is my current code,

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let uiImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            else if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
 
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how I currently display the chosen image.

```
 Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5803921569, green: 0.6392156863, blue: 0.5960784314, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 4))
```

This is how the current image cropper looks, as you can see it's a square. But instead of that I want a circle.
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the image to be an actual circle, or just displayed in a circle?

Comment: What does 'to make the image cropper circular' mean?  You want to remove a circular area from an image or get a circular area of an image?  Which is it?  If you are talking about the latter, then you want to clip a circular area of an image.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the difference is. I just want the image to be displayed as a circle, look at the edit, that's how I currently display the image. @Yrb

Comment: I suppose I want to get a circular area of an image. Do you know how to do that? @ElTomato

Comment: Define an area of a cutout with `UIBezierPath`.  Then use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I go about integrating this into my current code? Btw I'm that advanced yet @ElTomato